# Problem with constraint layout not fitting screen size

Tags: android

[image][image]I'm designing an android app with android studio using constraint layout but the preview on the android studio ide doesnt match after i install the app.i have posted two images to show the difference. I dont know where the problem is coming from and it has been bothering me for days.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/CardView.Light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="382dp"
        android:layout_height="420dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/media_image"
            android:layout_width="278dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="#03A9F4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/media_image" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Theme"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Lessons"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="Add"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="Cancel"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

---

Comment: did you mention about the blue rectangle

Comment: what do you want to achieve? which one is the desired layout?

Comment: please add your xml code and point out your desired output.

Comment: on an unrelated note, when you set your marginStart you don't need to set marginLeft also (on a Left to Right orientation). These two work exactly the same.

Comment: @ Nikos Hidalgo the app screenshot is my desired layout but then inorder to have it  i have to keep repositioning the imageview on the android studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ConstaintLayout` width should be `match_parent` and children's width has to be `0dp`(match constraints) with having `constraints` to its parent Left and Right.

Something like this:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

......

        <YourView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Of course container of this layout has to have match_parent width as well.

Comment: Ok let me change it and see what happens